# jQuery to read xml from different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, proxy

I am a newbie, please help me reading xml from different domain using jquery. 
Please help me out. I am using below code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",  
        url: "xmlname.xml", 
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: parseXml 
    });
});
```

But I want the url should be http://www.websiteName.com/xmlname.xml

Comment: I think that you can only retrive data from different domains if you use JSONP, but I might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can not access resources from other domains. This is a restriction of the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). @ianbarker is correct that using JSONP would allow you to work around this restriction.

---

**EDIT**

You could use something like this to proxy the request.

```
<%@ Language=vbScript%>
<%
    Dim xmlhttp 
    Set xmlhttp = Server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", "http://othersite/page.asp", false
    xmlhttp.Send Nothing
    Response.Write xmlhttp.responsexml.xml
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Much appreciated!! But is there a way around to load using proxy?

Comment: Yes, you could proxy the request through your web application as @Alan Beech suggests.

Comment: I only read this on google but dont know how to implement this. please help me.

Comment: Please give an example so I can better understand the function. ASP code

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what server side technology you are using. But in .Net MVC you'd call for the data server side via a controller and return it locally as json/xml.

Comment: http://hashworld.com.au/test/test.html Can you anyone help me find out action is not working on single click. I have to click twice to see the data

Answer (score 0):

create an asp page with just the following in and call that as if it were the remote xml page from jquery. As it is local you'll be able to query it.

Response.Buffer = true

Dim objXMLHTTP, xml, text

Set xml = Server.CreateObject ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 'Or if this doesn't work then try :
 'Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

xml.Open "GET", "", false

xml.Send

text = xml.ResponseText
 Response.write(text)

Set xml = Nothing